# Disable Sitecore Ecommerce cache building on startup

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Is there a way to disable Sitecore Ecommerce cache processing on startup?

This takes ages before its completed and Sitecore is running.

Sitecore version is 9.

```
11660 11:33:40 INFO  Commerce.Connector - Processing response from CE. Skipping
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for advice from Ryan Bailey.

The time it takes to rebuild the cache was caused by huge amount of products which were in the ECommerce engine.

The temporary solution for the development was to call the following APIs for the ECommerce server:

- CleanEnvironment
- InitializeEnvironment

Unfortunately the drawback of such solution was the fact that now there is no available catalogs in the ECommerce. Potentialy could be litigated by having limited product test data for dev environment.